# How to update field to add value to existing value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to update field to add value to existing value?
For example I have

Table name: `table`

```
id   credit
1      4
2      5
3      3
```

Is there a way to simply add value to the credit?
like

```
UPDATE table SET credit = '+7' WHERE id='1'
```

I want to add 7 to 4 so that the credit=11 where id='1'
How to do this?

Comment: what's the difference between your accepted answer than mine?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET credit = credit + 7 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 18):

This is just a simple `UPDATE`. Try the following.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Credit = Credit + 7
WHERE ID = 1
```

note that `ID = 1` and `ID = '1'` is the same as the server automatically parses it.

Comment: isnt it good idea to put `1` in ID=1 in single quote like `ID='1'`, so that a query doesnt throw a error if incase  the ID value is not defined?

Comment: the server automatically parses that value :D

Answer (score 14):

Simply use `credit = credit + 7` instead of `credit = '+7'` in `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE tablename SET credit = credit + 7 WHERE id = 1
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0101b/1)

Answer (score 9):

Try this code

```
UPDATE table SET credit = credit + 7 WHERE id='1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just try this...

```
UPDATE table SET credit = credit + 7 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

well '+' is an operator so u need to provide the parameter it requires.
'+' operator is an binary operator thus we need to provide two parameters to it
with the syntax

```
 value1+value2
```

though it may take parameters of many data types
by writing '+7' you are only sending a String value "+7" replacing your previous value

so u better use

```
UPDATE table SET credit = '+7' WHERE id='1'
```

don't confuse '+' operator with other increment operators

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to this with an 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' example(based on the answer by @hims056).  I found this answer but needed 'ON DUP...' so I figured may as well post it here.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
(`id`, `credit`)
VALUES (1, 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`credit` = `credit` + 7;
```

[See the SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f3af/1/0)