# How to get a numerical value from a text box and update a database with that numerical value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to insert a numerical value into a text box and then add that value to a value in a table when i submit is clicked.

For example I have a database with a table called customers. 
The table customers has a name and balance column.
I want to enter a number into a text box, and then when the submit button is clicked i want it to add the entered value to a value in the balance column, where it is updated.
In other words if the database column balance has a value of 50. Then when I enter a value, lets say 20, the updated balance in the database would be 70.

I have attempted this, but i have only incremented the value by 1, because I do not know how to make an entered textbox value into a variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
//if user is not logged in, do nothing
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    exit('Not logged in.');   
}

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classicmodels","root", NULL);   
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    exit('Database connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE customers SET balance = balance + 1 WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']) or exit("bind param failed.");
$stmt->execute() or exit("UPDATE failed.");
```

### UPDATED QUESTION STARTS HERE

//loggedin.php

```
<?php
    //if user is not logged in, then redirect to the login page
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
       header('Location: ./main.php');
    }

    //get the balance from database for logged in user
    //connect to the database
    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classicmodels", "root", NULL);  
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Database Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    //retrieve the click count for the logged in user
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT balance FROM customers WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
    $stmt->execute() or exit("SELECT failed.");

    //retrieve the firstname for logged in user
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT firstName FROM customers WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt1->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
    $stmt1->execute() or exit("SELECT failed.");

    //retrieve the lastname for logged in user
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT lastName FROM customers WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt2->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
    $stmt2->execute() or exit("SELECT failed.");

    //if there is no such user, then redirect to login page
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
    {
        header('Location: ./main.php');
        exit();
    }

    //extract the balance
    $row = $stmt->fetch() or exit("fetch failed.");
    $balance = $row["balance"];

    //extract the name
    $row = $stmt1->fetch() or exit("fetch failed.");
    $first = $row["firstName"];

    //extract the name
    $row = $stmt2->fetch() or exit("fetch failed.");
    $last = $row["lastName"];
?>

<head>
<title>LAB 3 - HTML & Web Programming</title>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

</head>

<!--<h1><center>LAB 3 - HTML & Web Programming</center></h1>-->
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6"><center>Banking Example</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        Welcome,<br> <?php print($first) ?> <?php print($last) ?>
    </td>
    <td>

        Your Balance is: $<?php print($balance) ?><br><br>
    <form action="/deposit.php" method=post>
Deposit: <input type="text" name="DepositAmount" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="/withdraw.php" method=post>
Withdraw: <input type="text" name="WithdrawAmount" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action = "logout.php" method = "post">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Logout"/>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="alert('Your Balance is: $<?php print($balance)?>')">Check Balance</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

<div id = "error_message"></div>

<script>
function record_click()
{
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(!httpRequest)
    {
        alert('Browser not supported');
        return;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        {
            if(httpRequest.status === 200)
            {
                if(httpRequest.responseText.length > 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'https://cse405-luisgeesb.c9users.io/login/deposit.php');
    httpRequest.send();
}

(function()
{
    var count = <?php print($click_count)?>;
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.onclick = function()
    {
        counter.innerHTML = --count;  
        record_click();
    }
})();    
</script>
```

//deposit.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //if user is not logged in, do nothing
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        exit('Not logged in.');   
    }

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classicmodels","root", NULL);   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Database connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE customers SET balance = balance + :DepositAmount WHERE email = :email");
    //$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']) or exit("bind param failed.");
    $stmt->bindParam(':DepositAmount', $_POST['DepositAmount']) or exit("bind param failed.");
    //$stmt->execute() or exit("UPDATE failed.");


$stmt->execute(array(':email'=> $_SESSION['email'],':DepositAmount' => $_POST['DepositAmount'])) or exit("UPDATE failed.");


?>
```

Comment: `balance + 1` => `balance + $varibleSubmitted`

Comment: seems good, but how can i make the value in the textbox a variable?

Comment: via an http form submit  and `$_POST`

Comment: ^ or   you could use    `$_GET`

Comment: It looks like you already know how to do the database part, so are you asking more about how to build the form for it? If that's the case you should include a minimal working example of your current form code as well.

Comment: Click here to see what im trying to do please. https://cse-320-luisgeesb.c9users.io/main.php

Comment: link requires login, code should be posted here, but anyway below answers probably solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
$sql = "UPDATE customers 
    SET balance = balance + :transaction 
    WHERE email = :email";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array( 
    ':email'=> $_SESSION['email'],  
    ':transaction' => $_POST['transaction'] 
    ))  
    or exit("UPDATE failed.");
```

And you make a `<form>` in html with an `<input type="text" name="transaction" />`

---

With your full code and a bit a clean, you have :

```
<?php
//if user is not logged in, then redirect to the login page
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
   header('Location: ./main.php');

//get the balance from database for logged in user
//connect to the database
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classicmodels", "root", NULL);  
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

try {
    // if we have a Deposit
    if (isset($_POST['DepositAmount'])) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare(
            "UPDATE customers 
            SET balance = balance + :DepositAmount 
            WHERE email = :email";
            );

        $stmt->execute(array( 
            ':email'=> $_SESSION['email'],  
            ':DepositAmount' => $_POST['DepositAmount'] 
            ));
    }
    // if we have a Withdraw
    if (isset($_POST['WithdrawAmount'])) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare(
            "UPDATE customers 
            SET balance = balance - :WithdrawAmount 
            WHERE email = :email";
            );

        $stmt->execute(array( 
            ':email'=> $_SESSION['email'],  
            ':WithdrawAmount' => $_POST['WithdrawAmount'] 
            ));
    }

    // anyway, we get our data back
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(
        "SELECT balance, firstName, lastName 
        FROM customers 
        WHERE email = :email"
        );

    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_SESSION['email']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

} catch (Exception $e) { // error handle
    exit('ERROR : '. $e->getMessage());
}


//if there is no such user, then redirect to login page
if(empty($row))
{
    header('Location: ./main.php');
    exit();
}

$balance = $row["balance"];
$first = $row["firstName"];
$last = $row["lastName"];
?>

<head>
<title>LAB 3 - HTML & Web Programming</title>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

</head>

<!--<h1><center>LAB 3 - HTML & Web Programming</center></h1>-->
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6"><center>Banking Example</center></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Welcome,<br> <?php print($first) ?> <?php print($last) ?>
        </td>
        <td>

            Your Balance is: $<?php print($balance) ?><br><br>
            <form action="" method=post>
                Deposit: <input type="text" name="DepositAmount" value=""><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <form action="" method=post>
                Withdraw: <input type="text" name="WithdrawAmount" value=""><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <form action = "logout.php" method = "post">
                <input type = "submit" value = "Logout"/>
            </form>

            <button type="button" onclick="alert('Your Balance is: $<?php print($balance)?>')">Check Balance</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

<div id = "error_message"></div>

<script>
function record_click()
{
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(!httpRequest)
    {
        alert('Browser not supported');
        return;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        {
            if(httpRequest.status === 200)
            {
                if(httpRequest.responseText.length > 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'https://cse405-luisgeesb.c9users.io/login/deposit.php');
    httpRequest.send();
}

(function()
{
    var count = <?php print($click_count)?>;
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.onclick = function()
    {
        counter.innerHTML = --count;  
        record_click();
    }
})();    
</script>
```

Comment: <form action="/deposit.php">
Deposit: <input type="text" name="transaction" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: @LuisGarcia `<form action="deposit.php" method="post">`, I'm using `$_POST` on my snippet ;)

Comment: Thanks this worked! Now for me to achieve this same goal without the page changing would require extra code?

Comment: @LuisGarcia you mean keeping your user on the same page ? or without any reload of the page ?

Comment: yes stay on the same page. because when i click submit it goes to the blank deposit.php page. is there a simple way to make this stay on the same page? @Blag

Comment: @LuisGarcia edit your question and your the code of both of your page please, it's not really hard to merge them

Comment: @LuisGarcia so you want to merge `loggedin.php` and `deposit.php` ?

Comment: i beleive so. So what i want to accomplish is: when i click on the deposit button, i want the change of value to be performed but instead of going to a blank page, i want to stay on the same page. would i just add the php code at the top of the loggedin.php file?

Comment: https://cse-320-luisgeesb.c9users.io/main.php if you would like to visualize what i mean. just log in with the given credentials.

Comment: i believe i just got it. what i did was add a header('Location: loggedin.php'); at the very end of the deposit.php file. is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: @LuisGarcia update of my anwser // But yes, the header solution you found is a cleaner way to do it. I explain : with header, you can keep a "one page per function", it help a lot when your code grow a bit.

Comment: @LuisGarcia you"re welcome ;) Don't forget to check the "this answer solved my question" on the top-left corner of answers if you're done with your question (it'll close is as "Solved")

Answer (score -1):

I'm not expert at PDO and I don't know if syntax like this will work or not but when the form is submitted, retrieve the form's new value (either $_GET or $_POST) and use that value instead of the number 1 in the statement ... something like ...

```
$new_value = $_GET['new_value_from_the_form'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE customers SET balance = balance + 
$new_value WHERE email = :email");
```

[How to update field to add value to existing value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742863/how-to-update-field-to-add-value-to-existing-value)

Comment: **Never put a `$var` in the sql query**, that's insecure / allow SQL Injection and is not the recommended way. See my answer for how to use prepared statement ;)

Comment: Agreed. I qualified mine and didn't see your post until after I sent it and yours is the correct way. The poster's first question seems to be about understanding retrieving $_POST or $_GET values from a form submittal.

Comment: yes, I saw you posting at the same time ;) *(btw, not my downvote, you can delete your answer if you want your points back)*