# Update/Adding New Value in the row mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a value (varchar) to an existing mysql table, for example I have a table like below

```
----------------
| id |  value  |
| 01 |    aa   |
----------------
```

I want to create the table above as the table below

```
----------------
| id |  value  |
| 01 |  aabb   |
----------------
```

as you can see, that I want to add the "bb" value in the "aa" table, but I have tried to use the code below but it did not work

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET value=value+'$newValue' WHERE id= '01'");
```

when I use the above code, the results I get differ from what I want

how to fix this problem?

Comment: `value=value+$newValue` you should do it like this.

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, I advice you using mysqli

Comment: Not sure if `+` works for strings. Might take a look at [concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742863/how-to-update-field-to-add-value-to-existing-value

Answer (score 2):

```
SET value=concat(value,'$newValue');
```

That's how it will work, you cannot add strings by `+`, use [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)  to add strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET value = CONCAT(value, 'bb') WHERE id = 01
```

Comment: id looks to be a string, so would need: WHERE id = '01';

Answer (score 0):

Use Concat, like so:

```
UPDATE tablename SET value = CONCAT(value, 'newvalue') WHERE id = '01';
```

You can read more about Concat [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET value=CONCAT(value, '$newValue') WHERE id= '01'");
```